# Comparing record value with another record different column value in a single table

Tags: sql, oracle

| Col A | Col B | Dist |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 50 |
| 2 | 1 | 100 |
| 3 | 4 | 100 |
| 4 | 3 | 200 |

I want to compare column record value to another column record value and calculate the difference for such kind of records.

| Col A | Col B | Dist Difference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 50 |
| 2 | 1 | 50 |
| 3 | 4 | 100 |
| 4 | 3 | 100 |

I tried below query, but I could get only matching records for one column value to another column value, however I need to take a difference of two records:

```sql
SELECT
    a.*
FROM
    table1 a
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            table1 b
        WHERE
            a.Col A = b.Col B and a.Col B= b.Col A
    )
and Col A  <> Col B
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self-join:

```sql
SELECT a.cola,
       a.colb,
       ABS(a.dist - b.dist) AS dist_difference
FROM   table1 a
       INNER JOIN table1 b
       ON (a.cola = b.colb AND a.colb = b.cola)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (cola, colb, dist) AS
SELECT 1, 2,  50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 4, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 3, 200 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| COLA | COLB | DIST_DIFFERENCE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 50 |
| 1 | 2 | 50 |
| 4 | 3 | 100 |
| 3 | 4 | 100 |

---

If you only want a single value for each pair then you can use `GREATEST` and `LEAST` and aggregate:

```sql
SELECT LEAST(cola, colb) AS cola,
       GREATEST(cola, colb) AS colb,
       MAX(dist) - MIN(dist) AS dist_difference
FROM   table1
GROUP BY
       LEAST(cola, colb),
       GREATEST(cola, colb)
```

Which outputs:

| COLA | COLB | DIST_DIFFERENCE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 50 |
| 3 | 4 | 100 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-ZCGlUOJ)

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to use the [MODEL clause](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/10g/r2/prod/bidw/sqlmodel/sqlmodel_otn.htm). It is very handy when you need multiple rows/columns calculations.

```sql
WITH      -- S a m p l e   D a t a    1:
    tbl (COLA, COLB, DIST) AS
        ( Select 1, 2,  50  From Dual Union All
          Select 2, 1, 100  From Dual Union All
          Select 3, 4, 100  From Dual Union All
          Select 4, 3, 200  From Dual 
        )
```

However, the question is a bit unclear. The rows are in paires and I'm not sure if you want the first of paired rows to keep it's DIST value and to calculate the difference just in the second paired row. If so, you could try it like here:

```sql
Select   COLA, COLB, Case When DIST = DIST_2 Then DIST Else DIST - DIST_2 End "DIFF"
From    ( Select ROWNUM "RN", COLA, COLB, DIST, DIST "DIST_2"
          From tbl  
          Order By COLA
        ) MODEL   
            Dimension By (RN, COLA, COLB)
            Measures(DIST, DIST_2)
            RULES ( DIST_2[ANY, ANY, ANY] = Nvl(DIST[CV(RN)-1, CV(COLB), CV(COLA)], DIST[CV(), CV(), CV()]) )
Order By RN
--  R e s u l t :
--        COLA       COLB       DIFF
--  ---------- ---------- ----------
--           1          2         50
--           2          1         50
--           3          4        100
--           4          3        100
```

On the other hand - if you want same calculated difference in both paired rows - try the following code:

```sql
--   M a i n   S Q L    2:
Select   COLA, COLB, ABS(DIST_2) "DIFF"
From    ( Select ROWNUM "RN", COLA, COLB, DIST, DIST "DIST_2"
          From tbl  
          Order By COLA
        ) MODEL   
            Dimension By (RN, COLA, COLB)
            Measures(DIST, DIST_2)
            RULES ( DIST_2[ANY, ANY, ANY] = Nvl(DIST[CV(RN)+1, CV(COLB), CV(COLA)], DIST[CV(RN)-1, CV(COLB), CV(COLA)]) - DIST[CV(), CV(), CV()])
Order By RN
```

The result for sample data provided is the same, but you will see the difference if you change the DIST value in the last row from 200 to 199.

```sql
WITH      -- S a m p l e   D a t a     2:
    tbl (COLA, COLB, DIST) AS
        ( Select 1, 2,  50  From Dual Union All
          Select 2, 1, 100  From Dual Union All
          Select 3, 4, 100  From Dual Union All
          Select 4, 3, 199  From Dual 
        )

--  R e s u l t  (for 1st code):
--        COLA       COLB       DIFF
--  ---------- ---------- ----------
--           1          2         50
--           2          1         50
--           3          4        100
--           4          3         99

--  R e s u l t  (for 2nd code):
--        COLA       COLB       DIFF
--  ---------- ---------- ----------
--           1          2         50
--           2          1         50
--           3          4         99
--           4          3         99
```